# What is the difference bewteen LDAP and OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

What are the differences between LDAP and Active OpenLDAP?

Comment: I believe LDAP is a "standard" and OpenLDAP is an open implementation of LDAP.  Did you mean to put "Active OpenLDAP"?  I think you may have mistyped.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the differences between LDAP

LDAP was originally a protocol, Lightweight Directory Access Protocol, and is now a directory service specification in its own right, including all kinds of schemas and extras.

> and Active OpenLDAP?

There is no such thing as 'Active OpenLDAP'. There is however [OpenLDAP](http://openldap.org), which is an open-source implementation of LDAP, both server and client.

Comment: There's also Active Directory, which is Microsoft's attempt at complying with the LDAP standard.